# What is the best Docker architecture with php, AngularJS, Nginx, Mysql

Tags: php, angularjs, docker, nginx

I have an AngularJS/PHP7/MySQL application and I want improve its architecture. Actually, it currently runs in separate docker containers.

- One container for both the front end and back end created with Angular JS and PHP respectively.
- One container for the database

I want to improve this setup and achieve something like this:

- One container with NGINX : port 80, 443
- One container with node and my AngularJS front : port 4200
- One container apache (or php fpm ?) with my backend PHP : port 81
- One container with MySQL : port 3306

And more broadly, is it a good thing to separate front and back ? For scaling problems later? And what kind of tools, I will use for these scaling problems? Docker Swarm, Kubernetes?

I don't know if it's a good approach. Could you help me to choose the right path for this application ? (Sorry for my English, I'm not native). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start looking into Docker Compose Basics first rather than trying to straightly dive into the deployment. This will help you to understand how to deploy multi container applications and the basic idea behind it. As per your scenario docker-compose allows you to define your NGINX container, Angular JS container (your front end), PHP (your back end) and your MySQL DB container, the ports which they are running on and also define overlay networks which you can separate container wise. Please see below resources, in  the 3rd link you can also visit a Docker Compose file which has defined exactly the same configurations as your current setup, just refer it after you get hang out of the basics.

[Docker Compose Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

[How to use Docker Compose](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-use-docker-compose/)

[Sample Docker Compose File](https://github.com/TOA/php-7-angular/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

When it comes into Docker Swarm and Kubernetes those are container orchestration platforms. Both of these allow you to run containers in clusters which means you can replicate the number of containers running each service (service here means one of your containers, i.e NGINX Container) to make them highly available. Imagine one of your NGINX containers fails and you have defined to run 3 NGINX containers on your Docker Swarm or Kubernetes cluster and your users won't be affected though one of your NGINX container is down as there are two more other containers running. There are some differences between Docker Swarm and Kubernetes and its up to you to decide on what tool to use after you get these basics right. If you are starting out with docker-compose going into Docker-Swarm will be bit easy.

[Difference between Docker Swarm and Kubernetes](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm-whats-the-difference/)

Also I have added an answer explaining the use of Docker Swarm on to scenario like yours, read it so you can get an idea on how to deploy your app with Docker Swarm.

[My Answer on Docker Swarm Use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49072602/4334340)